# XSL for-each on space-separated attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, tei

for my research project, I have this document in XML/TEI

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" >
<body>
    <div>
        <p>
            <span target="#" type="passage" ana="Tag957 Tag874">
                <span target="#" ana=""/>
            </span>
            <seg><date when="1980-01-01" type="date_seg"/>blabla blabla
                 blabla blablablabla blablablabla blablablabla blablablabla bl
            </seg>
            <span target="#" type="passage" ana="Tag1657 ">
                <span target="#" ana=""/>
            </span>
            <seg><date from="1980-01-03" to="1980-01-05" type="date_seg"/>blabla
            </seg>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</TEI>
```

I need to extract for each Tag contained in span/@ana : the date and the string length of the following node seg. With the condition that if we incounter the date attribute @from or @to, I just need the value of the @from.
What I need would look like that :

```
Tag957;1980-01-01;88
Tag874;1980-01-01;88
Tag1657;1980-01-03;11
```

I tried this, but I don't know how to express that for-each is applyed to one attribute's value at a time

```
<xsl:template match="tei:p">
        <xsl:for-each select="tei:span">
                <xsl:value-of select="./@ana"/>
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::tei:seg/tei:date/@from or following-sibling::tei:seg/tei:date/@to">
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::tei:seg/tei:date/@from"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::tei:seg/tei:date/@when">
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::tei:seg/tei:date/@when"/>
            </xsl:if>
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="string-length(following-sibling::tei:seg)"/>
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$newLine"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor respectively which XSLT version do you use/can you use?

Comment: I use XSLT processor in Oxygen software, the one I chose is Saxon-HE9.6.0.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XSLT 2.0 you can use `tokenize` to identify the different values in the attribute value, then you can rewrite your code as

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:for-each select="span">
            <xsl:variable name="span" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(@ana, '\s+')[normalize-space()]">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
              <xsl:if test="$span/following-sibling::seg[1]/date/@from or $span/following-sibling::seg[1]/date/@to">
                <xsl:value-of select="$span/following-sibling::seg[1]/date/@from"/>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test="$span/following-sibling::seg/date/@when">
                <xsl:value-of select="$span/following-sibling::seg/date/@when"/>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="string-length($span/following-sibling::seg[1])"/>
              <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
            </xsl:for-each>    
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuPL.

Comment: Thanks, it worked well on the XML I gave. I tested it on my other files and I had to add seg[1] in the second xsl:if cause it was retrieving the dates of all other siblings seg

Answer (score 3):

You made only a **single loop** for `span` elements. It's not enough.

Actually, for each such `span` you have to:

- Read the `ana` attribute.
- Tokienize it with a space (if you can, use XSLT 2.0, it has this function).

For each resulting token (not for the whole value of `@ana`) you have to perform the inner `for-each` loop:

- Find **only the first** following `seg` sibling and its child `date` element:
  `select="following-sibling::tei:seg[1]/tei:date"` (note that I added *[1]*).
- Check whether it contains required attributes (`from`, `to` or `when`).

If it does, then:

- Print the current token extracted from the current `ana` attribute.
- Print the requred dates according to your need (from the current `date` element).
- Print the rest of things to be printed.

It is only a sketch, I omitted such details as keeping the current values from both loops in respective variables.

I hope it will help you to reach the final result.

Answer (score 1):

**XSLT-1.0**

I create a recursive template to tokenize values inside `ana` attribute, and call it for each span. I had to add a space on line 8 for the template to work:
`<xsl:with-param name="remaining-ana-val" select="substring-after(concat(./@ana,' '),' ')"/>`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="tei:p">
        <xsl:for-each select="tei:span">
            <xsl:call-template name="recurse_ana">
                <xsl:with-param name="ana_val" select="substring-before(./@ana,' ')"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="remaining-ana-val" select="substring-after(concat(./@ana,' '),' ')"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="seg" select="following-sibling::tei:seg[1]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="recurse_ana">
        <xsl:param name="ana_val"/>
        <xsl:param name="remaining-ana-val"/>
        <xsl:param name="seg"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($ana_val) > 0"><xsl:value-of select="$ana_val"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$seg/tei:date/(@when|@from)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="string-length($seg)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="'&#x0D;'"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="recurse_ana">
                <xsl:with-param name="ana_val" select="substring-before($remaining-ana-val,' ')"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="remaining-ana-val" select="substring-after($remaining-ana-val,' ')"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="seg" select="$seg"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
Tag957;1980-01-01;105 
Tag874;1980-01-01;105 
Tag1657;1980-01-03;19
```

Online link: http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLJ/2

Comment: Thanks for your proposition. I tested it on other files and it appeared though that it only process span that have multiple values in @ana and not the ones with only one value. It's strange :-)

Comment: @r.let The second span in your sample XML has and additional space inside the `ana` attribute. I utilize it to tokenize the attribute values. Maybe other `span` do not have that additional attribute and hence are left out.